# How can I set a QPushButton to grow vertically?

Tags: qt, user-interface

**Background**: I need [Command Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/ctrl-command-links)-like controls. Normally, I would use Qt's [builtin `QCommandLinkButton`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcommandlinkbutton.html), but in this case I need to also support Right-to-Left layouts. Regrettably, `QCommandLinkButton` doesn't seem to respect `Qt::RightToLeft` when set explicitly via `setLayoutDirection`. There also doesn't seem to be a way to override the layout direction via style sheets.

I tried to work around this issue by using `QPushButton`: I instantiated `QPushButton` and replaced its contents with a custom layout containing two labels stacked vertically. This did not work because `QPushButton` refused to expand horizontally.

Failing to make `QPushButton` instances work, I decided to try sub-classing it. No matter what I tried (overriding `sizeHint`, setting vertical `sizePolicy` to expanding, `resize`ing explicitly, etc) the button refuses to grow more than 30 pixels high.

If I change `QPushButton` to `QWidget`, the new widget grows normally.

**The question**: How can I force a `QPushButton` to grow vertically and fit its inner widgets? If this is not possible, what are my options for a button-like widget that is both visually and behaviorally consistent with `QPushButton` and other "native" controls?

Comment: Would this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61571582/qt-qpushbutton-vertical-size-fit-to-contents/61571835 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get the button to grow normally by setting the maximum height to 16777214 (instead of the default 16777215), and then setting the content margins of the button to 10.

Perplexingly, the default maximum height of a `QPushButton` should be plenty, but for some reason it refuses to grow past 30 pixels unless the maximum height is explicitly set to something else.

Answer (score 0):

Place the button inside a layout and set its `vertical size policy` to `Maximum`.

[image]

Comment: I'm using Qt Widgets to dynamically generate my user interface at runtime. The closest setting I found was [QLayout::setSizeConstraint](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#sizeConstraint-prop) which I suspect is not relevant. I did try set the constraints to maximum and no-constraint to no success.